# Do likelihood attributes make sense with a single if statement?

Tags: c++, c++20, likely-unlikely

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely) and [this documentation](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4741.pdf) do not state explicitly that likelihood attributes won't work with a single `if` statement. Or, I just do not understand what is meant by *alternative path of execution*. So that's my question, will the attribute, say, `[[unlikely]]`, work in the case below?

```
if (condition) [[unlikely]] {
    do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c1093923733a1072a237f112e3239b5ebd88eadd/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/variant#L466

Comment: The alternative path is doing nothing (or not executing the body, if you like). That is, it's the same as `if (condition) { do_stuff(); } else {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. The alternative, `[[likely]]`, path is the one where the condition is `false`, that is, the path not calling `do_stuff();`. That becomes the path it'll try to optimize for.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

inline void do_stuff() {
    std::cout << "Surprise!\n";
}

int main(int argc, char**) {
    if (argc == 0) [[likely]] {
        do_stuff();
    }
}
```

Assembler with `[[likely]]`:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Surprise!\n"
main:
        test    edi, edi
        jne     .L4
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edx, 10
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L4:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

With `[[unlikely]]` (and without attribute at all):

```
.LC0:
        .string "Surprise!\n"
main:
        test    edi, edi
        je      .L8
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.L8:
        push    rax
        mov     edx, 10
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rdx
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

Those are two slightly different outcomes and without knowing too much about assembler, I'd say the effect of putting `[[likely]]` there is clear. It looks to me that putting `[[likely]]` there made it inline the function while `[[unlikely]]` left it as a function call.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense and clang respects it nicely.
Try compiling:

```
void do_stuff(void);


void unlikely(int condition){
    if (condition) [[unlikely]] {
        do_stuff();
    }
}

void likely(int condition){
    if (condition) [[likely]] {
        do_stuff();
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hzahxzT3v

Clang at -O3 yields:

```
unlikely(int):                           # @unlikely(int)
        test    edi, edi
        jne     .LBB0_2
        ret
.LBB0_2:
        jmp     do_stuff()@PLT                # TAILCALL
likely(int):                             # @likely(int)
        test    edi, edi
        je      .LBB1_1
        jmp     do_stuff()@PLT                # TAILCALL
.LBB1_1:
        ret
```

Notice that both of these function tail-call optimize the call to `do_stuff()` (by `jmp`ing into it rather than calling it).

The difference is that with the unlikely case, control flows naturally into `ret` (return instruction), branching only to `jmp do_stuff()` if the condition is satisfied (`jne` stands for `jump not equal` meaning not equal to zero, i.e., jump on `condition`).

With the likely case, on the other hand, control flows naturally into the `jmp do_stuff()`, branching only to `ret` if the reverse of the condition is satified (`je` stands for `jump equal` meaning equal to zero, i.e., jump on `!condition`).

This is how it should be. x86_64 processors predict first encounters of a branch as not taken, so the optimal layout is for the expected paths to follow naturally and for the unexpected ones to be branched into.

Comment: What escapes me is who the heck thought it was a good idea to standardize `likely`/`unlikely` as statement attributes. Makes far more sense to annotate expressions with it like it's been done by compilers so far (via `__builtin_expect`) as that way it can work with both the ternary (`?:`) and with short-circuiting operators (`&&` and `||`) inside of `if`. Invention by committee is a disease.